# Is this "trope" intentional in Haikyuu?

Tags: haikyuu

In *Haikyuu*, one will find scenes in which characters' faces affects the wires of net i.e the wires of the net fades out where the faces coincides. This is somewhat making the animation unrealistic. Is this intentional? Did the author intentionally faded out the wires? What advantages is it serving? For context, see this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is done by the animators on purpose I believe. It's so the viewers can see the full extent of the facial expressions of the person behind the net. This actually happens very often in Haikyuu. If you notice the net isn't faded out over his whole head it's just faded out over his face. This makes sense because his hair doesn't really matter to the context or anything, but his facial expressions can tell us a lot. I don't think this makes it that unrealistic.